# Exception "Com_alter_db_upgrade" is coming while clicking on Dashboard in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, workbench

I am getting exception while clicking on "Dashboard" in mysql workbench, the exception is message box that says "An unhandled excepiton occurred ('Com_alter_db_upgrade'). Please refer to the log files for details."  I have installed mysql 8.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you running the mysql workbench for MySQL 8? Have you looked at the details in the log files? What did you do in workbench?

Comment: i don't see any details in mysqld.log.

Comment: @sam the 'log files' it says is not `mysqld.log` which is the server log, but the workbench's log which is a client program. So the log file you want to inspect is `~/.mysql/workbench/log/wb.log`.

Answer (score 0):

Just like me, you were probably using an old version of MySQL Workbench to connect to a new instance of MySQL 8.

If you refer to [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-nutshell.html#mysql-nutshell-removals) you'll see that 'Com_alter_db_upgrade' status variable was removed from MySQL 8.

Upgrading MySQL Workbench version, or using it to connect to equivalent MySQL old versions should be fine.